# How can we load sys.config in slave nodes in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, distributed, erlang-otp

I have encountered an issue retrieving sys.config values using application:get_env/2 in slave nodes. I have started slave nodes using peer:start/1 as follows.

```
spawn_node(NodeName) ->
    Cookie = atom_to_list(erlang:get_cookie()),
    InetLoaderArgs =
        "-loader inet -hosts 127.0.0.1
        -config ../../config/sys.config
        -setcookie "
        ++ Cookie,
    {ok, _Pid, Node} = start_node(NodeName, InetLoaderArgs),
    pong = net_adm:ping(Node),
    ct:log("Slave started as ~p~n", [Node]),
    ok = rpc:block_call(Node, code, add_paths, [code:get_path()]),
    {ok, _} = rpc:block_call(Node, application, ensure_all_started, [toy_kv]),
    Node.

start_node(NodeName, InetLoaderArgs) ->
    peer:start(#{name => node_name(NodeName),
                 host => "127.0.0.1",
                 args => [InetLoaderArgs]}).
```

When slave nodes try *application:get_env/2*, it returns ***undefined***. It seems the configuration is not loaded in peer nodes. What am I missing here?

PS -

After loading the application, I know we can set the configurations by executing `application:set_env(Application, Par, Val)`

```
ok = rpc:call(Node, application, set_env, [toy_kv, mode, distributed])
```

But I want to know, in `peer` nodes, whether we can load the configuration using the `sys.config` file or not.

Comment: `application:get_env(Application, Param)`: Returns `undefined` if any of the following applies:

The specified application is not loaded. The configuration parameter does not exist. The process executing the call does not belong to any application.

Comment: @7stud, Thank you for your response. 
As I'm calling `application:ensure_all_started(Application)`, if there are no errors in the application, it should load, right? So, the only thing that can happen is that the configuration parameter does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can sys.config to args option of peer:start(Options) like this,

```
InetLoaderArgs = ["-loader", "inet", "-hosts", "127.0.0.1",
            "-config", "../../config/sys.config"
            "-setcookie", Cookie]
```

I have written [this blog post](https://hasitha-dhananjaya.blogspot.com/2024/01/how-to-create-salve-nodes-in.html) on starting slaves using the peer module. Also, [this blog post](https://max-au.com/2022/01/06/peer/) comprehensively explains distributed app testing in Erlang.